# Is it possible to pass the NEW and the OLD tables from a trigger into a procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it possible to pass the NEW and the OLD tables from a trigger into a procedure in MySQL?
I suspect no, since there is no such a datatype as table that a procedure accepts.
Any workarounds possible?

Ideally it would look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Product_log AFTER UPDATE ON Product
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    call logChanges(OLD, NEW);
  END;
```

Comment: I am having the same issue/requirement. Did you got any work-around (probably efficient one?)

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible because there is no NEW or OLD *table*.  The entire trigger is related to *the* table - the "new" and "old" refer to the rows and the values they contained *before* and *after* the event that was triggered.  In other words, your example would be:

```
call logChanges(OLD.customername, NEW.customername)
```

You could also save all the OLD data in a history table (which I expect logchanges does anyways), basically being a clone of the production table something like this:

```
BEGIN
    IF OLD.customer_name != NEW.customer_name
    THEN
            INSERT INTO myTable_chagne_history
                (
                    customer_id    ,
                    customer_name  ,
                    another_field  ,
                    edit_time
                )
                VALUES
                (
                    OLD.customer_id,
                    OLD.customer_name,
                    OLD.another_field  ,
                    NEW.time_edit_was_made
                );
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly pass each field:

```
CALL logChanges(OLD.colA, OLD.colB, NEW.colA, NEW.colB);
```

Or if `logChanges` must be sufficiently generic that it can handle such calls from different tables, one could concatenate the field values into a single string using a suitable delimiter (e.g. the [unit separator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f/index.htm)):

```
CALL logChanges(CONCAT_WS(CHAR(31), OLD.colA, old.colB),
                CONCAT_WS(CHAR(31), NEW.colA, NEW.colB));
```

Or if data types must be preserved, one could insert the records into a temporary from which `logChanges` reads.